# Find single dataframe row index matching 2 columns conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and I need to get the index of the row that match the values with 2 columns.

For example, the dataframe below:

```
Name     City   Country
Pietro   Roma   Italy
Maria    Milan  Italy
Pietro   NY     USA
```

In this case, I need to get the index of Pietro|Roma|Italy, seaching for Name and City columns only.

I tried doing the code below, but it returns all the rows that matches the 2 columns.

```
idx = np.where(dataframe[dataframe["Name"] == 'Pietro'],dataframe[dataframe["City"] == 'Roma'])
```

But it returns an array of indexes [[0,2],[0]] and I need to return index 0 that is where I have Name = 'Pietro' and City = 'Roma'

**Updated with Solution**

The solution is:

```
dataframe.index[(dataframe["Name"] == 'Pietro')&(dataframe["City"] == 'Roma')][0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
dataframe.index[(dataframe["Name"] == 'Pietro')&(dataframe["City"] == 'Roma')]
```

Comment: This is correct, but returns the index object, (Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'). If you want just the value of the index, add [0] to the end

Comment: It worked combining answers: dataframe.index[(dataframe["Name"] == 'Pietro')&(dataframe["City"] == 'Roma')]
[0]